# Client-side event and Server-side event conflict on RadTreeView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, treeview

I am using `Telerik RadTreeView` which consists of `onNodeClick` - a serverside event and `OnClientDoubleClick` - a client-side event. I want to use `OnClientDoubleClick` functionality for my `model popup`. Problem that I am facing is that code-behind event conflicts with my client-side event.
When I double click any node on `treeview`, javascript function  `OnDoubleClick` runs as well as `treeViewAssets_NodeClick` method which happens when the user selects a node (single click) on server side.
Here's my treeview contol

```
 <telerik:RadTreeView ID="tvAssets" runat="server" AccessKey="W" CheckBoxes="True" CheckChildNodes="True" TriStateCheckBoxes="True" OnNodeClick="tvAssets_NodeClick" OnClientDoubleClick="onDoubleClick">
```

I've tried to stop the codebehind method but I wasn't successful.It only made the treeview nodes unselectable. I also tried passing value on `hiddenfields` from javascript so that based on value I could skip codes in codebehind method but code behind method always retrieves null value that I passed in javascript function.

```
 protected void tvAssets_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = hdisDoubleClick.Value;
        string doubleClick = "";
            if (value == null || value == "")
            {
                doubleClick = "false";
            }                
            if (doubleClick == "True")
            {
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                hdisDoubleClick.Value = "False";
                return;
            }
       //code for tvAssets_NodeClick

    }
```

I tried using session, viewstate, cookies instead of hiddenfield but the value I get is always null. I also tried using `button.click()` function inside javascript to pass value but `tvAssets_NodeClick` method on `codebehind` fires eliminating chances to pass any value.

I am new at programming so I must be doing this wrong, trying to get a value from clientside method when there is a postback happening.. which creates new instance of the controls in webform or something like that.. maybe that's why I am getting `nullexception` errors.

I can't remove `tvAssets_NodeClick` method because it gives me values regarding whether that particular node can be deleted or not, whether it is enabled or not etc..

So is there any way I can do the following:

1. Pass value from client side when there is postback happening.
2. Stop codebehind method from javascript so that `tvAssets_NodeClick` doesn't run OR any other alternatives you can think of.

My client side event is as following:

```
function onDoubleClick(sender, eventArgs) {
        document.getElementById("<%=hdisDoubleClick.ClientID %>").value = "True";           
        //document.cookie = "CookieName=True;"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a tricky case - you have subscribed to the single click event (server-side) and double click event (client-side).

Probably when you do a double click - the first click already fires the server side event and the javascript code of the double click event handler does not execute completely.

Maybe it is a good time to evaluate whether you need both of these events.

Comment: Yep.. thought so... probably it isn't possible at all..So I am moving forward with only the server side event i.e. tvAssets_NodeClick to do the both job.